What is the correct way of defining an affine transform with NonlinearStateSpaceModel?
I am trying to construct an affine transform (y=g(x-a)) to be applied to the output of a discrete time model using SystemsModelSeriesConnect. The documentation gives a working example in the continuous time domain. I have tried to work with discrete time models without success. To hopefully simplify things I tried to construct a system in continuous time and the convert to discrete time. The result throws errors. Below is my simplified attempt:
(*a model *)
ssm = StateSpaceModel[
   y''[t] == -y[t] - y'[t] + f[t], {y'[t], y[t]}, {f[t]}, {y[t]}, t];

Plot[
 OutputResponse[ssm, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]

(* an affine transform *)
affxform = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, {2 (u - 3)}}, {}, {u}]

   
(*transform the output of ssm*)
seriesSSM = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[ssm, affxform];

(*this works *)Plot[
 OutputResponse[seriesSSM, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}] // Evaluate, {t, 
  0, 10}]

(* convert to disctrete time model *)
dtm = ToDiscreteTimeModel[seriesSSM, .5]

(* this throws errors *)OutputResponse[dtm, 
 UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}]

(* \
Control`LegacySimulationsDump`outputResponseIterate[{{0.`,0.5`,0.75`,\
0.75`,0.5625`,0.28125`,0.`,-0.2109375`,-0.31640625`,-0.31640625`,-0.\
2373046875`,-0.11865234375`,0.`,0.0889892578125`,0.13348388671875`,0.\
13348388671875`,0.1001129150390625`,0.05005645751953125`,0.`,-0.\
03754234313964844`,-0.056313514709472656`},{0.`,0.`,0.25`,0.625`,1.`,\
1.28125`,1.421875`,1.421875`,1.31640625`,1.158203125`,1.`,0.\
88134765625`,0.822021484375`,0.822021484375`,0.86651611328125`,0.\
933258056640625`,1.`,1.0500564575195312`,1.0750846862792969`,1.\
0750846862792969`,1.0563135147094727`}},{NonlinearStateSpaceModel,{{0.\
5` (f[t]-y[t]-Subscript[\[FormalX], 1][t])+Subscript[\[FormalX], \
1][t],y[t]+0.5` Subscript[\[FormalX], 1][t]},{2 \
(-3+y[t])}},{{Subscript[\[FormalX], 1][t]\[Rule]0,y[t]\[Rule]0},{f[t]\
\[Rule]0}},t,{2,1,1},0.5`},{0,0},{UnitStep[t]},{t,0,10},False,{}] *)

(*try with AffineStateSpaceModel*)
afssm = AffineStateSpaceModel[seriesSSM]

afdtm = ToDiscreteTimeModel[afssm, .5]

OutputResponse[afdtm, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}]

(* same error*)


Specify the input as a sequence.
OutputResponse[dtm, Table[UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10, 0.5}]];
ListStepPlot[%, DataRange -> {0, 10}]



Thank you!  It seems I was correctly applying the transform, but looking at the output wrongly.  I have been exploring your wonderful tool set. I want to emulate a plant in hardware by downloading a model to a microcontroller. The output is expected to be bipolar, but the DAC only outputs positive values. The transform will translate the output to the positive half plane.
